# matlab gui make array public

Tags: arrays, user-interface, matlab, matlab-guide

in my one of my callbacks, i load a wav file then plot it in an axes.
 in another callback, i try to play the wav file but its not working.
 please help, how can i play it??

```
function btnload_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.wav','Select Data File');
[y,fs] = wavread([pathname filename]);
axes(handles.axes1)
plot(y);
title('ORIGINAL AUDIO SIGNAL');
ylabel('t');
guidata(hObject, handles); %updates the handles




function btnplay1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
soundsc(y,fs);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to maintain [application data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f5-998352.html#f5-998711) in GUIDE-generated GUIs, one way is to use the `handles` structure which gets passed  around to all callback functions:

```
function btnload_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    %# read WAV file
    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.wav','Select Data File');
    [y,fs] = wavread([pathname filename]);

    %# plot wave
    axes(handles.axes1)
    plot(y);
    title('ORIGINAL AUDIO SIGNAL');
    ylabel('t');

    %# save it to handles structure
    handles.y = y;
    handles.fs = fs;
    guidata(hObject, handles);      %# updates the handles
end

function btnplay1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    %# retrieve the wave data, and play the sound
    soundsc(handles.y, handles.fs);
end
```